# Add a new configurations block to admin/config

Tags: 7, routes

I'm trying to add a new configurations block to `admin/config` (just like "People", "Media" and "System").

I tried copying and modifying the relevant lines from `modules/user/user.module` but my block doesn't show and directly going to the link `admin/config/mysite` results in an access denied message.

The sub pages appear directly under the `Administration > Configuration` menu in the Administration module (but not in the page `admin/config`.)

Any idea how to fix this?

```
$items['admin/config/mysite'] = array(
  'title' => 'My Site',
  'description' => 'Configure My Site settings.',
  'position' => 'left',
  'weight' => -20,
  'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
  'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
  'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
  'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
);

$items['admin/config/mysite/page1'] = array(
  'title' => 'Sub page 1',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('mysite_admin_1'),
  'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
);

$items['admin/config/mysite/page2'] = array(
  'title' => 'Sub page 2',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('mysite_admin_2'),
  'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my own problem. The reason the links appeared where they did and not under my new block is that I've moved existing items to a new location, which means they were still in the original location in the menu configuration screen. Moving them manually to their correct location solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if we don't specify the `access callback` property in `hook_menu()` we get a notification as below:

```
Notice: Undefined index: access in _menu_translate() (line 778 of includes/menu.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: access in menu_get_item() (line 464 of includes/menu.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: access in menu_execute_active_handler() (line 499 of includes/menu.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: access in menu_tree_page_data() (line 1167 of incldes/menu.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: access in menu_tree_page_data() (line 1167 of includes/menu.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: access in menu_local_tasks() (line 1845 of includes/menu.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: access in menu_tree_page_data() (line 1167 of includes/menu.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: access in menu_tree_page_data() (line 1167 of includes/menu.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: access in menu_tree_page_data() (line 1167 of includes/menu.inc).
```

To avoid this the above code should be edited a bit by adding an `access callback` property

```
$items['admin/config/mysite'] = array(
 'title' => 'My Site',
 'description' => 'Configure My Site settings.',
 'position' => 'left',
 'weight' => -20,
 'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
 'access callback' => 'user_is_admin'
 'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
 'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
 'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
);

$items['admin/config/mysite/page1'] = array('title' => 'Sub page 1',
 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
 'page arguments' => array('mysite_admin_1'),
 'access callback' => 'user_is_admin'
 'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
);
```

And the notice is removed. :)

Comment: No this will result in an error that "user_is_admin" function is not defined. Also, "access callback" defaults to "user_access" so it's not necessary to define it unless overriden somewhere else either.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using below code.

```
$items['admin/config/myblk'] = array(
'title' => 'Title of the block',
'description' => 'description',
'position' => 'left',
'weight' => -25,
'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
);

$items['admin/config/myblk/myblk-setting'] = array(
'title' => 'Link to settings',
'description' => 'Description about link',
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('call_your_setting_form'),
'access arguments' => array('administer authentication'),
'weight' => 10,
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way we can add the module link to Admin config page by menu management. Here is the below link to access the menu management.

http://yoursite.com/admin/structure/menu/manage/management

Thank you!!!